# Get Records count of specified date-range from database, if no record present for one of the date then return count as '0'

Tags: c#, linq, date

I want List (containing HoursCount and date) of record from database for specifies date-range

if for some date, records are not available in database then that date should be in list with count = 0

```
// Where GetDateWistUsage is...

public List<GraphData> GetDateWiseUsage(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
    return Set.Where(x => x.Date >= startDate.Date && x.Date < endDate.Date)
        .GroupBy(x => x.Date)
        .Select(x => new GraphData { Date = x.Key.Date, TotalHoursCount = x.Sum(i => i.TotalHours }).ToList();
}

// Where GraphData is
public class GraphData
{
     public DateTime Date { get; set; }
     public double TotalHoursCount { get; set; }
}
```

Here, suppose if we are passing Date 1-Dec-2018 to 20-Dec-2018 and for 15-Dec-2018 no record present in database. In that case, List should also contain 15-Dec-2018 with TotalHoursCount = 0

Comment: You might want to show us the correct part of your application. GetDateWiseUsage would have to return the right data, surely? Even if you want to make the change in the API method, we have no idea what type `AppUsageGraph` is.

Comment: Thanks John for asking details.. I have edited question, Is it helpful for understating my Problem statement

Comment: Can you also include the GetDateWiseUsage method, and basically anywhere up to and including the database query?

Comment: Hey John, I have removed Unwanted method, and added some extra description below code, Hope this will help out to understand with actual problem...

Comment: You'll probably need to generate a date range for the missing dates and integrate that with the rest of your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create some dummy data to fill in the gaps. Since you're doing a `Sum`, you can just create some dummies of your input data.

To do so, I've assumed that `Set` is `List<SourceData>` - change this as necessary:

```
public class SourceData
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public long TotalHours { get; set; }
}

public class GraphData
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public long TotalHoursCount { get; set; }
}
```

I've then added a method to get a date range (upper bound exclusive):

```
public static IEnumerable<DateTime> GetDateRange(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
    return Enumerable.Range(0, (endDate - startDate).Days).Select(d => startDate.AddDays(d));
}
```

Finally, I've updated your GetDataWiseUsage method to generate the date range and convert it into dummy source data:

```
public static List<GraphData> GetDateWiseUsage(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
    return Set.Where(x => x.Date >= startDate.Date && x.Date < endDate.Date)
    .Concat(GetDateRange(startDate, endDate).Select(date => new SourceData() { Date = date, TotalHours = 0 }))
    .GroupBy(x => x.Date.Date)
    .Select(x => new GraphData { Date = x.Key, TotalHoursCount = x.Sum(i => i.TotalHours) }).ToList();
}
```

I've changed your code to group by `x.Date.Date` rather than `x.Date`, as it seems that you want a separate grouping per day, rather than per unique time. The group by will not group the dummy data with the real data, and factor it into the sum.

You *could* add the dummy data *afterwards* but it seems easier/less work to do it beforehand.